# History of logon times in AD?

Tags: windows, active-directory

We are interested in finding out when a particular user has logged in to our domain. Is there any way we can track this? I realise we could write a script from this point on but as this has only just come to light, is it possible historically? The event viewer on the local machine does not seem to contain the information.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can trawl through all Domain Controller logs looking for EventID 672 (Kerberos Authentication Ticket Granted). If you want to be absolutely sure that the user was subsequently successfully logged in you may want to correlate this with a subsequent event with EventID 673 indicating that there was an actual service ticket granted, not just the ticket-granting ticket that 672 tracks. There is a good write up about these and related EventIDs in [this Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742435.aspx).

This is about the only way I know of that can allow you to track historical AD logons after the fact at the domain level if you are not using some third party mechanism or script that is already in place. The content of these Events will contain the user name and the ip-address of the system the logon originated from (the specific details of those fields are in the linked article but are obvious when you look at them). It's important to remember that this will only be of use if you have Domain Controller logs that go back far enough and it can be a lot of work if you have a large number of DC's. There is no way to use these events (or any other kerberos related events) to track logoff times as those are not mediated by domain controllers.

At the workstation level you can dig through the logs looking for Event ID 528 Type 2 to track local interactive logons (even those using Domain Accounts) and EventID 538 type 2 to track logoff events which can give you a better idea of the actual times the user spent logged in. The key problem with these is that they are only useful if you know exactly which systems the user logged in from in the first place. The Type field is critical as there will typically be many more EventID 528\538 events of Type 3 that indicate connection\disconnection from network resources such as file shares etc. You can find more information on these events in [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140714).

For Windows 2003 functional level domains the AD keeps a consistent copy of the "LastLogonTimeStamp" attribute replicated across all DC's but that will simply tell you the last successful log on time and wont give you any idea of the history of logons.

Comment: +1. I user, and can recommend LogParser (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) to retrieve the event log details in an easier to digest format.

Comment: This looks to be what we're after.  The event log on our server (WS2003) only goes back to 1st Jan this year....are logs before this date deleted or are they stored somewhere?
Thanks

Comment: That depends on whether you are doing something to archive the log data which you would almost certainly be aware of if you were. From a Windows AD perspective the answer is no, once a log is cleared or overwritten it's gone for good. If you have older full backups of DC's you could restore them but that is a very dangerous exercise that must be carried out in an isolated environment.